# Unable to handle UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in React server-side render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React application that renders on both client and server. When any component's render() fails (due to a bug in my code, e.g. trying to read a property of an undefined object), then if I'm navigating from another page in the browser, then I get a full stack trace in the browser developer console.

However, when I trigger a server-side render of the same code (by directly pointing the browser to the problematic route that contains the faulty component), then I just get errors like these in the server's console:

`(node:97192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagDefinitionId' of undefined`

With no stack trace, it's a little hard to debug.

QUESTION: **Is there a way to blanket-catch-all render() failures during server-side renders?**

The code that triggers a server-side render in response to a Node-Express endpoint being requested is below. I believe the unhandled promise rejection occurs inside renderToString(), but this function returns a string, not a promise.

`

```
import configureStore from '../../redux/store';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import RouterContext from 'react-router/lib/RouterContext';
import createMemoryHistory from 'react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory';
import match from 'react-router/lib/match';
import template from './template';
import routes from '../../routes';

const clientAssets = require(KYT.ASSETS_MANIFEST);

app.use((request, response) => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory(request.originalUrl);

    match({ routes, history }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
            response.status(500).send(error.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            response.redirect(302, `${redirectLocation.pathname}${redirectLocation.search}`);
        } else if (renderProps) {
            // This is the initial store
            const store = configureStore();

            // When a React Router route is matched then we render
            // the components and assets into the template.
            const render = () => {
                // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
                const initialState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());

                let isNotFoundRoute = false;
                if (renderProps.routes[1].path === '*') {
                    isNotFoundRoute = true;
                }

                // Populate the HTML document with the current redux store
                response.status(isNotFoundRoute ? 404 : 200).send(template({
                    root: renderToString(
                        <Provider store={store}>
                            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                        </Provider>
                    ),
                    cssBundle: clientAssets.main.css,
                    jsBundle: clientAssets.main.js,
                    initialState,
                }));
            };

            // Fetch the components from the renderProps and when they have
            // promises, add them to a list of promises to resolve before starting
            // a HTML response
            fetchComponentData(store.dispatch, renderProps.components, renderProps.params).then(render);
        } else {
            response.status(404).send('Not found');
        }
    });
});
```

`

I think the only import of custom code that may be relevant here is template.js:

`

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

export default (vo) => {
    const helmet = Helmet.rewind();
    return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()} >
            <head>
                ${helmet.title.toString()}
                <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta charSet='utf-8' />
                <meta httpEquiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <meta name="theme-color" content="white" />
                ${helmet.meta.toString()}
                ${helmet.link.toString()}
                <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" sizes="16x16 32x32" type="image/png" />
                <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
                ${vo.cssBundle ? '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + vo.cssBundle + '">' : ''}
            </head>
            <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()} >
                <div id="root" class="root"><div>${vo.root}</div></div>
                <script>
                    window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${vo.initialState}
                </script>
                <script async src="${vo.jsBundle}"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;
};
```

`

Comment: How about just handling the error instead of leaving it unhandled? `.then(render).catch(err => { console.error(err); response.status(500).send("sorry, we're looking into it") })`?

Comment: Yes, [there's also a catch-all](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) that you can use to log your stack traces

Comment: ...I thought I'd tried that without success... yet your first suggestion works just fine. Can you submit this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [a catch-all](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) that you can use to log your stack traces of unhandled rejections, but you'd better simply handle them. Indeed when something in your `render` function throws an exception, nothing catches that.

I would recommend to restructure your script to

```
app.use((request, response) => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory(request.originalUrl);

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        match({ routes, history }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) reject(error);
        else resolve({redirectLocation, renderProps});
    }).then(({redirectLocation, renderProps}) => {
        if (redirectLocation) {
            return {status: 302, target: redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search};
        } else if (!renderProps) {
            return {status: 404, content: 'Not found'};
        } else {
            const store = configureStore();
            return fetchComponentData(store.dispatch, renderProps.components, renderProps.params).then(() => {
                const initialState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
                const isNotFoundRoute = (renderProps.routes[1].path === '*');
                const content = template({
                     root: renderToString(
                        <Provider store={store}>
                            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                        </Provider>
                    ),
                    cssBundle: clientAssets.main.css,
                    jsBundle: clientAssets.main.js,
                    initialState,
                });
                return {status: isNotFoundRoute ? 404 : 200, content};
            });
        }
    }).catch(err => { // THIS IS IMPORTANT!
        console.error(err); // or err.message and err.stack and everything, maybe including route
        return {status: 500, content: 'Sorry, we\'ll look into it'}; // or err.message if you trust it
    }).then(({status, target, content}) => {
        if (status >= 300 && status < 400)
            response.redirect(status, target);
        else
            respose.status(status).send(content);
        if (status >= 400)
            console.debug(…)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this sounds like a problem that's hard to deal with in React@15. The only approach I can think of is to add error handling to all render-methods in all components, and that's just not feasible.

The problem with errors and React up until now is that any error will send React into an unstable state. Luckily, `react@next` (16) comes with `componentDidCatch` - a new lifecycle method that lets you catch and handle any error in your component or any descendants (children).

You can read more about this new behavior [in the React team's blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html).

Hope this helps!